# XMLSerializer and other troubles

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to serialize standard employee - department structure

```
[Serializable]
public class EmployeeBean
{
  [XmlElement( "Id"            )] public string Id           { get; set; }
  [XmlElement( "Id"            )] public string Name         { get; set; }
  [XmlElement( "DeparmentName" )] public string EmpDeparment { get; set; }
  [XmlElement( "Age"           )] public double Age          { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Department
{
  [XmlElement( "Id"          )] public string             Id          { get; set; }
  [XmlElement( "Name"        )] public string             Name        { get; set; }
  [XmlElement( "Description" )] public string             Description { get; set; }
  [XmlElement( "Employees"   )] public List<EmployeeBean> Employees   { get; set; }
}
```

and the lists to serialize

```
private BindingList<EmployeeBean> _empList ;
private BindingList<Department>   _dptList ;

XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Department));

// Create a new file stream to write the serialized object to a file
TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(path);
SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, _dptList);
```

with serialize it just says error when trying to init serializer and with LINQ it just says it is created unevenly.

Comment: Can you post the full exceptions please?

Comment: Both your name and id properties are mapped with `[XmlElement("Id")]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there can't be two attributes [XmlElement("Id")] otherwise exception will occur.

```
    public class EmployeeBean
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]    
    public string Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [XmlElement("Name")]    
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

And another problem is XmlSerializer(typeof(Department)) **but  _dptList is BindingList**.

```
//XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Department));
XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BindingList<Department>));
```